# Using synchronous file-IO library in asynchronous code

Tags: rust

I want to use library with synchronous file IO in asynchronous application. I also want all file operations work asynchronously. Is that possible?
Something like this:

```
// function in other crate with synchronous API
fn some_api_fun_with_sync_io(r: &impl std::io::Read) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    // ...
}

async fn my_fun() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let mut async_file = async_std::fs::File::open("test.txt").await?;

    // I want some magic here ))
    let mut sync_file = magic_async_to_sync_converter(async_file);

    some_api_fun_with_sync_io(&mut sync_file)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this magic exists yet, but you can conjure it up yourself with `async_std::task::block_on`:

```rust
fn magic_async_to_sync_converter(async_file: AsyncFile) -> Magic {
    Magic(async_file)
}

struct Magic(AsyncFile);

impl SyncRead for Magic {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        block_on(self.0.read(buf))
    }
}

use std::io::Read as SyncRead;

use async_std::{
    fs::File as AsyncFile,
    io::ReadExt,
    task::{block_on, spawn_blocking},
};
```

But since `some_api_fun_with_sync_io` is now doing blocking io, you'll have to shove it into a blocking io thread with `spawn_blocking`:

```rust
spawn_blocking(move || some_api_fun_with_sync_io(sync_file)).await?;
```

You might want to revise your design and see whether you can do without this though. `spawn_blocking` is still marked as `unstable` by `async_std`.

Comment: Thanks for idea about `async_std::task::block_on`. I already tried to write same but didn't know how to use .await in sync code. `async_std::task::block_on` solves it. But it looks like you meant `impl Read for Magic` instead of `impl SyncRead for Magic`?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion, I have the habit or renaming things when using both sync and async facilities in one piece of code.  See that `use std::io::Read as SyncRead`?

Comment: Opps I did't notice `use std::io::Read as SyncRead`. I post some benchmarks of your idea below

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking idea of @Caesar :

```
use async_std::prelude::*;
use std::time::*;

struct AsyncToSyncWriteCvt<T: async_std::io::Write + Unpin> (T);

impl<T: async_std::io::Write + Unpin> std::io::Write for AsyncToSyncWriteCvt<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        async_std::task::block_on(self.0.write(buf))
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        async_std::task::block_on(self.0.flush())
    }
}

fn test_sync<W: std::io::Write>(mut w: W) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    for _ in 0..1000000 { w.write("test test test test ".as_bytes())?; }
    Ok(())
}

async fn test_async<T: async_std::io::Write + Unpin>(mut w: T) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    for _ in 0..1000000 { w.write("test test test test ".as_bytes()).await?; }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    async_std::task::block_on(async {
        // bench async -> sync IO
        let now = Instant::now();
        let async_file = async_std::fs::File::create("test1.txt").await?;
        let sync_file = AsyncToSyncWriteCvt(async_file);
        test_sync(sync_file)?;
        println!("Async -> sync: {:.2}s", now.elapsed().as_secs_f32());

        // bench sync IO
        let now = Instant::now();
        let sync_file = std::fs::File::create("test2.txt")?;
        test_sync(sync_file)?;
        println!("Sync: {:.2}s", now.elapsed().as_secs_f32());

        // bench async IO
        let now = Instant::now();
        let async_file = async_std::fs::File::create("test3.txt").await?;
        test_async(async_file).await?;
        println!("Async: {:.2}s", now.elapsed().as_secs_f32());

        Ok(())
    })
}
```

This code shows "sync -> async" file writing as fast as "async" file writing but less fast then direct sync writing. `BufWriter` allow to speed up and to close the speed gap between sync and async